# How to setup apache virtual host on docker

Tags: virtualhost, docker, apache2

i'm new to docker and i would like to setup a virtualhost on my docker machine in order to access it this way `http://myapp.dev` or `*.myapp.dev` (accept any subdomain).

i tried few things, none of them seemed to work

1. Setting VIRTUAL_HOST env variable in `docker-compose.yml` file
2. creating an apache2 config file at the root of my project and link it as a volume in the docker compose (eg: `./php-apache.conf:/et/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf` and added `127.0.0.1   myapp.dev` in my host machine's `/etc/hosts` file

it sound like something pretty common so i must be missing something.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is my config:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    php-apache:
        build:
            context: ./php-apache
            args:
                uid: ${UID}
        container_name: laravel-app
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.dev
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=#${UID}
            - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=#${UID}
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            # tried with the above line w/o success
            - ./php-apache.conf:/etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf
        ports:
            -  8000:80
        networks:
            backend:
                aliases:
                    - laravel-app
    mysql-db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: mysql-db
        volumes:
            - ./run/var:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_rootpwd
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
            - MYSQL_USER=my_user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_pwd
        networks:
            backend:
                aliases:
                    - db
networks:
    backend:
        name: backend-network
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get update

# 1. development packages
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    curl \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    g++

# 2. apache configs + document root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# 3. mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    iconv \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip

# 5. composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer


# 6. we need a user with the same UID/GID with host user
# so when we execute CLI commands, all the host file's ownership remains intact
# otherwise command from inside container will create root-owned files and directories
ARG uid
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/devuser devuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser
```

`/etc/hosts` (from host machine)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   anon-870Z5G-880Z5F
127.0.0.1   myapp.dev
# i also tried with the docker ip like 127.20.0.3   myapp.dev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Have you registered that domain name? You do know that HTTPS is required to use `.dev` right?

Comment: Gosh i didn't know, it was actually just it ! Can you write an answer so i can mark it as correct (and also can you please provide the link from where you get that information from ?).
i replaced `.dev` with `.com` and its working like a charm, thx a lot.